# Use nearest neighbor search for hover in column chart

Tags: highcharts

In Highcharts line charts, if you hover anywhere in the chart, it will display a tooltip on the nearest data point, using a nearest neighbor search ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joliss/o4zkyt7a/1/)).

```
chart: {
    type: 'line'
},
```

[image: line chart with hover]

But in column or bar charts, it will only show a tooltip if hover the columns themselves. If you hover above, it won't show a tooltip ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joliss/o4zkyt7a/2/)).

```
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
```

[image: column chart with hover]

I'd like to get the same nearest-neighbor-search behavior in the column chart. Is this possible?

I found the [plotOptions.column.findNearestPointBy](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.findNearestPointBy) option, which says:

> Applies only to series types using nearest neighbor search (not direct hover) for tooltip.

But I don't know how to enable nearest neighbor search.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts series like column requires direct hover to apply a tooltip. It is defined by hard-coded `directTouch` property: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/parts/ColumnSeries.ts#L564

As a solution you can use shared tooltip: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pyja037s/

Or add a plugin that allows the required behavior, for example:

```
(function(H) {
    H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.directTouch = false;

    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'getHoverData', function(
        proceed, 
        existingHoverPoint, 
        existingHoverSeries, 
        series, 
        isDirectTouch, 
        shared, 
        e
    ) {

        var chart = this.chart,
            hoverData = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)),
            hoverPoint = hoverData.hoverPoint,
            pointX = hoverPoint && hoverPoint.x,
            pointIndex;

        this.chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
            pointIndex = s.xData.indexOf(pointX);
            if (pointIndex >= 0) {
                if (
                    s.points[pointIndex] !== hoverPoint &&
                    Math.abs(
                        s.points[pointIndex].shapeArgs.x + chart.plotLeft - e.chartX
                    ) < Math.abs(hoverPoint.shapeArgs.x + chart.plotLeft - e.chartX)
                ) {
                    hoverPoint = s.points[pointIndex];
                    hoverData.hoverPoint = hoverPoint;
                    hoverData.hoverSeries = s;
                    hoverData.hoverPoints = [hoverPoint];
                }
            }
        });

        return hoverData;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4bw1no9h/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stickyTracking

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts